# How to add a dynamic content in a admin page

Tags: magento-2.1, admin, uicomponent

For example, in dashboard, I have a model edit form to edit the model which complete by UI component.

Now, I want add a **dynamic link** field in the edit page. Which is a link like `.../admin/model-child/index/index/?id=(model_id)`, when click it navigate us to a dashboard page which show the model child listing. How to achieve that?

The difficult points is

1. How to add the custom link field.
2. How to put the dynamic **model_id** in the model-child link.

---

More general question is:

How to add a **dynamic content** in a admin page?

Comment: in magento 2 or 1 ?

Comment: @AasimGoriya Magento2, the question tag show that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the example, the purpose is to add a dynamic link content, but doesn't need to post it, so we don't need UI component, we could **use layout to add dynamic content**.

### Update layout

In the layout file `model_index_edit.xml`, below the uiComponent add a block `<block class="the-block-class" template="Vendor_Module::model/dynamic-link.phtml"/>`, like below

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <uiComponent name="model_index_form"/>
    <block class="the-block-class" template="Vendor_Module::model/dynamic-link.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

### Create the block to get dynamic link

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\the-path;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class (Name) extends Template
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        array $data = [],
        Http $request
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function getLink()
    {
        $modelId = $this->request->getParam('model_id');
        $route = "model-child/index/index/";
        $params = ["id" => $modelId];
        return $this->getUrl($route, $params);
    }
}
```

### Create the template

Create the file `dynamic-link.phtml` in the `.../Vendor/Module/view/templates/view/model/` directory.

```
<a href="<?php echo $block->getLink(); ?>">Show the child-model listing</a>
```

That's all.

---

The answer of more general question is: In the above codes, change the get dynamic content function base on needs.

Hope others could give some different solution, like the solution of **using UI component to add dynamic content**.